# directionsService.route doesn't sync well

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am facing a weird case, I am using google directionsService.route. but it doesn’t sync well. Here is my code:

```
angular.forEach(requestArray, function(v, i) {
    directionsService.route(v, function(result, status) {
        var googleLeg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
        // sth else...
    });
});
```

As you can see, I am looping the location Array into the route. every time I fire the function, it will go through the `requestArray` first, (if we make a breakpoint on the line (`var googleLeg = result.routes[0].legs[0]`), it doesn’t reach there until it goes through all the `requestArray`.(i from 0 - length); then it will have the second loop for directionsService.route( at this time, it will reach to line(`var googleLeg = result.routes[0].legs[0]`); Any idea about this?

Comment: I did some search, looks like forEach function doesn't provide a promise, is there any way I can add a promise for each circle?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your problem is that calling a google service is an asynchronous call, and you are not guaranteed when the callback will execute.  If you need to process `requestArray` synchronously, here is what you can do:

```
function start() {
    // create a copy of request array
    var stuff = [].slice.call(requestArray);
    function continueSync() {
        // stop the recursion if we have nothing left to process
        if (!stuff || stuff.length == 0) return;
        // grab the first item off of the stuff queue
        v = stuff[0];
        stuff = stuff.slice(1);
        // call to google
        directionsService.route(v, function(result, status) {
            var googleLeg = result.routes[0].legs[0];
            // sth else...
            // now continue processing the rest of the stuff queue through tail recursion
            continueSync();
        });            
    }        
    // kick off our recursive processing
    continueSync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that calling a google service is an asynchronous call, you could prove to generate threads

Comment: This is an answer; but could you expound on what they could do better?